# Heirloom mailx does not verify its own S/MIME-signed messages?

Tags: smime, mailx

I finally set up a Comodo S/MIME certificate using Heirloom mailx. Testing with Thunderbird I'm able to receive signed (and even encrypted) messages without any errors or warnings. However, if I use Heirloom mailx as the receiving client I get the following:

```
? verif                                                                        
Message 1: Error with certificate at depth: 0
 issuer = /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO Client Authentication and Secure Email CA
 subject = /emailAddress=user@example.com
 err 20: unable to get local issuer certificate
Error verifying message 1: error:21075075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error
```

Any ideas? One more thing: this error is not present when I send the same signed messages from Thunderbird to mailx, only from mailx to mailx (same/different machines).

Thanks!

Edit: Just in case, here is my `.mailrc` file:

```
set from=user@example.com
set smime-sign-cert=/home/user/cert.pem
set smime-sign
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting -- `unable to find local issuer certiicate` -- typically means that the underlying OpenSSL libraries can't find the Certificate Authority certificate that was used to sign your S/MIME certificate.  Thunderbird, notably, has it's own list of valid certificate authorities that may be more comprehensive than what is available by default on your local system.

The `smime-ca-dir` and `smime-ca-file` directives can be used to point `mailx` at an appropriate CA certificate.

Comment: Thanks larsks. What I can't understand, then, is that when I receive in mailx a signed message sent from Thunderbird it verifies! How could this happen? It looks like my version of mailx does, after all, know about Comodo. In any event I tried pointing `smime-ca-file` to a file containing everything between `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` in my certificate, to no avail.

Comment: Remember the the `smime-ca-file` should be pointing at the Comodo CA certificate, not at *your* certificate.

Comment: OK, I tried it and it unfortunately didn't do it. But my point is that even without it it successfully verifies "Comodo-signed" messages sent from other clients. Intuitively it seems to me there is a problem at the time of composing the message. By the way, would you recommend a specific Comodo CA Certifcate from http://goo.gl/qWGJ4 ? I went with the "[New] InstantSSL CA Bundle", but didn't try them all. Thanks again!

Comment: I would need to set up my local mailx for smime to help out any further, and it's unlikely I'm going to get to that for a few days.  Sorry!  If I do get things set up I'll check back in here.

Comment: Thank you very much once again. Worry not, as this is clearly a fringe experiment/doubt! (I guess somebody agreed and voted to close the question!)